# set variable to null when iterator.remove()

Tags: java

I'm making a 2D shooting game, where you can shoot enemies and it will explode. And here's my render method:

```
public void renderEnemies(Graphics2D g) {
    for (Iterator<Enemy> it = enemies.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Enemy enemy = it.next();
        enemy.render(g);
        if (enemy.die) { // die
            it.remove();
            playSound(4);
            corpses.add(new Corpse(1, enemy.x, enemy.y));
            currentEnemyLife = 0;
        }
        if (enemy.x < 0) { // out of screen
            if (!enemy.die) {
                hero.LIFE--;
            }
            it.remove();
            currentEnemyLife = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Well, what I want to do is, set the enemy that was removed to null, so the garbage collection can remove it from the JVM. I tried to add `enemy = null;` when `it.remove();` was executed. But it seemed just deleting the variable `enemy` that I created using `it.next();` , not the actual enemy.
The method that I used for adding an enemy was `enemies.add(new Enemy());`.

I checked the memory by using `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` and it kept increasing until maximum, and the game crashed.

Comment: You don't have to set enemy = null, 1. what the estimate maximum memory? 2. probably you have another reference to enemy (if this the problem), Try check count of objects (by their type) from java heap

Comment: the maximum memory was 259522560, and I dont have any reference to enemy.

Comment: You will get much more information why you get out of memory using memory analyzer

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the memory analyzer! lol I've never heard about it and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it.remove` will remove the reference of the current Enemy instance from the `enemies` collection. If that's the only reference to the instance, it will become eligible to garbage collection. There's no need to set the local `enemy` variable to null, since it will be overwritten in the next iteration of the loop anyway.

Your memory problem may be elsewhere. When you remove an `Enemy`, you often create a `Corpse` instance. You should check the size of the `corpses` collection, to see whether it grows too much.

Comment: I have already checked the corpses size, and it works fine because I also have a similar method to renderEnemies that will remove the corpse.

Comment: @KongponCharanwattanakit In that case your problem may be elsewhere. I suggest you add debug prints that display the size of both the enemies and corpses collections, to see if the problem is one of them. If not, you should look elsewhere.